# How to translate Java construtor to Kotlin properly?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a Java class which extends AsyncTask like this:

```
class PostLocationTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private String responseServer;
    private double latitude, longitude

    public PostLocationTask(double latitude, double longitude){
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

}
```

My goal is to translate the code into Kotlin. Now I have this:

```
 companion object {
        class PostLocationTask internal constructor (context: PostLocationActivity): AsyncTask<String, Void, String?>(){

            private var responseServer = ""
            private var lat = 0.0
            private var lon = 0.0

            class PostLocationTask(var currentLat:Double, var currentLon:Double){
                lat = currentLat
                lon = currentLon
            }
        }
}
```

Android Studio red-underlines those 2 lines inside the constructor, saying "Expecting member declaration". Wrapping those 2 lines inside "init {}" block will change the error message into "Unresolved reference: lat", for example.

What's the correct translation, then?

Answer (score 1):

Do this.

```
import android.os.AsyncTask
import android.os.Build
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.CUPCAKE)
internal class PostLocationTask(
    private val latitude: Double, 
    private val longitude: Double) : AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {
        
        private val responseServer: String? = null

        override fun doInBackground(vararg strings: String): String? {
            return null
    }
}
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I think so

```
class PostLocationTask 
constructor(var latitude: Double, var longitude: Double) : AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {
    private var responseServer: String? = null

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin has [two types of constructors](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors). First one is that goes after class name and second is that contains body of class and is declared as 'constructor'

In your case I'd make something like

```
class PostLocationTask(
    var latitude: Double? = null, 
    var longitude: Double? = null
) : AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {
    var responseServer: String? = null
    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: String?): String = getLocationFromServer()
}
```